# Django union two tables into single model

Tags: django, django-models

I have an external database which I can't modify in any way (read-only). It has three tables - `Company` (`id`), `CompanyContact` (`company_id`, `contact_id`), `Contact` (`id`, `company_id`).

Basically, `Contact` has a nullable foreign-key to `Company` table and it works as many-to-one, but if company_id is `null`, I have to look into `CompanyContact` table, which is many-to-many kind relationship.

How can I combine these two tables (`Contact` and `CompanyContact`) into one model - `Contact`? In other words, how can I get all contacts for a given company?

In SQL that would be something like:

`select contact.id from contact where company_id = XXX
  union
 select contact_id from companycontact where company_id = XXX`

Django models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, db_column='id')

    class Meta:
        managed = False


class Contact(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, db_column='company_id')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

I don't have a model for `CompanyContact`. And there is nothing to show in views because that basically is my question, how to get contacts for a given company.

Comment: can you clear up the table/column mix up in your question please

Comment: Show us the models.py and view ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original tables in your database are not properly structured. It's incorrect that the contact field should have a `company_id` field. That needlessly complicates all queries (raw SQL or Django) because an additional check is needed on the contact_id field.

On the other hand it's perfectly legit for two entities in a many to many relationship to have exactly one mapping instead of many. So there isn't one clear answer to this question. I suppose your best bet would be to add a ManyToMany field as well. I am making this suggestion purely on the fact that you say the data is **read only**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, db_column='company_id')
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company, related_name='companies')


    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

Comment: Not sure I've understood your first paragraph about contact field having a contact_id field? Contact table has a company_id field, (which I guess is due to historical reasons), but no contact_id and there is another table CompanyContact storing many-to-many relationship. In any case, I can't modify anything there, so I need to work around it.

Comment: You are right, I have those improperly structured tables, but nothing I can do about them (my guess, that they'd been set so to be backwards compatible). Adding another model for many-to-many relation, to map column names seems to solve my problem, though I still have to merge those two company fields together.

Comment: Are you at least allowed to make a view on that table?

Comment: Yes, I can add a view. Ah, always forgetting about this possible solution (I think I will do just that now). Thank you!

Comment: glad I brought it up :-)